# Standard error of the mean for a questionnaire?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, survey

I have the standard deviations and means of 7 questions of a questionnaire and also the sample size. How can I calculate the standard error of the mean of the total questionnaire? I know SEM is standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size but I don't know how to calculate the total SDs from individual SDs and means to put in this formula.

Comment: By total questionnaire, I assume you mean the sum of the individual question scores or similar? You won't be able to calculate that if you don't also know (or make an assumption on) the covariance between the questions.

Comment: yes, the mean and its standard error of measurement taking the scores for all the questions into account. I only have the mean and SD for each question and the sample size. Could you please expand on your response a little bit?

Comment: You can't obtain an answer with such limited information, because you have no knowledge of the correlations among the responses.

Comment: Could you please write down the formula for calculating the standard error in this type of situation? I wasn't able to find it. I feel seeing the formula and its factors help clarifying it for me.

Comment: You compute the total of each questionnaire and apply standard formulas to those data.